# Plugin architecture on .NET Core at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, plugins, assemblies

I'm trying to design a custom plugin architecture for my .net-core (1.1.0) project and I'm facing problems loading external assemblies that have references to dll not already referenced by the main application.

I want to be able to load runtime assemblies that are in a specific folder structure, to instantiate all types defined in those dll, that implements a specific interface.

I can load assemblies and find the types I want to instantiate, but then an error says that an assembly can't be found. The missing assembly is an assembly referenced only in my plugin dll, and so I'm wandering how to solve 3rd party assembly dependency in .net-core!

How should I publish my plugin dll?
I would like to avoid copying every plugin referenced library.

Did I have to use the produced `deps.json` file?
If yes, how can I restore missing packages if I just ships the .dll and the `deps.json` file? Is it possible?

Any alternative?

Comment: When a plugin references an assembly not included in the hosting application, then you'll have to ship it with the plugin. The only other alternative I can think of would be removing the reference.

Comment: I think there should be a way to "restore" missing packages like the "dotnet restore" command does, so I'm wondering if including a project.json in plugin folders and run "dotnet restore" on those folders could help somehow.
Moreover i would like to prevent shipping same referenced assemblies in case of different plugins that use same dependencies